# google analytics v4 service unavailable

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I have a problem with getting data via Google Analytics Reporting API. 
Here is my v4 GA Reporting API query for YESTERDAY data:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer %ACCESS_TOKEN%" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet" -d '{"reportRequests":[{"viewId":"%VIEW_ID%","dateRanges":[{"startDate":"2017-11-27","endDate":"2017-11-27"}],"dimensions":[{"name":"ga:adContent"},{"name":"ga:keyword"}],"dimensionFilterClauses":[{"operator":"AND","filters":[{"dimensionName":"ga:source","operator":"EXACT","expressions":["%MY_FILTER%"]}]}],"metrics":[{"expression":"ga:transactions","formattingType":"INTEGER"},{"expression":"ga:transactionRevenue","formattingType":"FLOAT"}]}]}'
```

I get correct answer with returned data in JSON format.

But this query for TODAY data is failed with answer

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 503,
    "message": "The service is currently unavailable.",
    "status": "UNAVAILABLE"
  }
}
```

This behavior of system repeats if I am trying to use v3 GA Reporting API. "YESTERDAY" query

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer %ACCESS_TOKEN%" "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:%VIEW_ID%&dimensions=ga:adContent&metrics=ga:goal1Completions&start-date=2017-11-27&end-date=2017-11-27&start-index=1&max-results=50"
```

returns correct data. "TODAY" query

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer %ACCESS_TOKEN%" "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:%VIEW_ID%&dimensions=ga:adContent&metrics=ga:goal1Completions&start-date=2017-11-28&end-date=2017-11-28&start-index=1&max-results=50"
```

returns error

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"internalError","message":"There was an internal error."}],"code":500,"message":"There was an internal error."}}
```

Also there is no such problem with another google analytics accounts.

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is likely just a temporary issue. I just tried the [Request Composer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/request-composer/) and it seems to work.  See [Error handling table](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/errors#error_table)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried to make requests fro 3 hours and "today" query have not returned correct answer. But it works today.